# regex for subtitles

Tags: java, regex, srt

I need to parse some srt files and I am looking for a regex (for JAVA) that matches the times sections. What I want is to read the file line by line and if the lines are numbers or times sections skip them.

Example, given:

```
1
00:00:01,357 --> 00:00:03,323
You took this case
without running it by me.

2
00:00:03,359 --> 00:00:04,825
- Jessica--
- That's enough. Dump it.
```

I want to match the lines

```
00:00:03,359 --> 00:00:04,825
```

and

```
2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to match only **2** ??

Comment: What do you mean by **2**? The number of occurrences?

Comment: I have just update the answer

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes the 2 was to explain that I want to match both numbers and times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match number:

> ^\d+$

Match time

> ^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}$

For both condition

> (^\d+$)|(^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}$)

As I see in your format, number is before time so you just have to use match time to get line index and re move by index-1 and index

---

More clear about the regex time

> ^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}$

Start

> ^

From the begin of the text

> \d{2} or [0-9]{2}

Two digit only

> : or :{1} or [:]{1}

One comma : only
...

> , or ,{1} or [,]{1}

One comma , only

> \d{3} or [0-9]{3}

Three digit only

> .*

Every thing, have or not have value are ok

The past: again check time format

> $

end of text

It means from to end of that text have to match that condition

Comment: Drop the `{1}` quantifiers, they are redundant. Since `\d` in Java matches `[0-9]`, you can shorten the time regex to `^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}.*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}$`

Comment: As for `^([0-9]+)|([0-9]{2}[:]{1}[0-9]{2}[:]{1}[0-9]{2}[,]{1}[0-9]{3}.*[0-9]{2}[:]{1}[0-9]{2}[:]{1}[0-9]{2}[,]{1}[0-9]{3})$`, the regex is wrong, since it will try the first branch and grab only the hour in the timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for the first comment (+1), the second comment I dont understand because I am not good at English but I tried it and it ran.

Comment: It only works because you just fixed it following my comment. In the previous revision, you didn't specify $ in the first alternation.

Comment: Oh yes sorry for my mistake, I tested it and saw. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

for first line *00:00:03,359 --> 00:00:04,825* or *00:00:01,357 --> 00:00:03,323* below code may be useful.

```
String strLine = "00:00:01,357 --> 00:00:03,323";
System.out.println(strLine.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d,\\d\\d\\d --> \\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d,\\d\\d\\d"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to take the ending time of each subtitle:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}$
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eR2sF0/1)

Explaining:

```
\d{2}:      # a two-digits number followed by a ":" character
\d{2}:      # ""
\d{2},      # a two-digits number followed by a "," character
\d{3}       # a three-digits number
$           # matching only at ending lines
```